# How do I save Mathematica parameters and later access them with C++?

Tags: c++, wolfram-mathematica

At the moment, I call a C++ function from a dynamic library in Mathematica with given arguments/parameters. These include strings, integers, sparse matrices etc.

```
output = dllfunction[string, int, int, SparseMatrix, outputLocation,...];
```

Within the dynamic library, the arguments are loaded using `<WolframLibrary.h>`. Now I want to separate the Mathematica part from the C++ part.

How do I save the Mathematica parameters so I can load them in a separate C++ executable using `<WolframLibrary.h>`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. what do you mean the arguments are loaded using WolframLibrary.h? Do you mean the function prototypes? Or is the header file loading the library? And the point of a dll is so that they can be loaded into any executable which wants to utilise them.

Comment: The arguments are loaded with functions from <WolframLibrary.h>, e.g. MArgument_getInteger(), into the dll. So the question is: how do I save the arguments such that I can load them as before? I want to run C++ code without Mathematica.

Comment: I still don’t understand what you mean by saving the arguments

Comment: I want export the arguments/parameters and save them into a file, like Mathematica's Save[] or DumpSave[].